# Remove Find a different "First Last Name" section on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

On one's public LinkedIn profile, there are two sections on the right side:

1. Viewers of this profile also viewed
2. Find a different

I know how to remove the first one, but how do you remove the second (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set this, it looks like a setting only LinkedIn controls.

A possible way to not have "Find a different" appear next to your profile is to change your name to something so unique no one else in the LinkedIn database will have any slight variation on it.

If other users have the same first and last name as your profile, including short names (e.g. Sam/Sammy/Samantha/Samuel/Samelly), they may appear in that box.

If LinkedIn can't find anyone that shares that, they will not show the suggestions box.

But this is not a guaranteed method.